# Does WP7 or Mango support Vcard (vcf files) with photo?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to import a vcf file with a photo (encoding base64).
When I click on the vcf file through the web browser or the email, I get a dialog with the contacts details but the photo is not added.
I tried to create other vcf files using some online tools like this one [http://mobile.dangooli.com/vCard/]
but I get the same result, no photo is added.

Is there any way to add a contact with a photo by just clicking on a file?
Does wp7 or mango support another protocol for importing contacts with photos?

Or are the photos diregarded deliberately?

Thank you

Comment: Since this is not a technical quest per-say, it would be better off on the [App Hub Forums](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/). Since you won't be able to code your own technical solution for it, regardless of the answer, it's to be considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.